# Sync between machines

Tags: usb, hard-drive, firefox, thunderbird, sync

If I would install Ubuntu on both my computers (laptop+desktop) would be possible to do the same sync of data (Firefox/Thunderbird/VariousDataFiles) through my usb hdd?
How should I do this? Sync the /home folders on both computers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Linux world all user's own data and configurations are placed in home directory /home/username/
For example Firefox save its profile data in /home/username/.mozilla/firefox/profilename.default

So to backup or sync application data between computers you need to find where it stored in your home directory and just copy application's data directories to another computer.
Of course you need to have installed your applications on both computers.

Comment: And to do that, you could use Freefilesync (GUI) or rsync, or something similar.